# How to run a python file as a module with the "Run Python File" button in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code 1.74.3 with the Microsoft Python extension v2022.20.2.

I am talking about the button to run a python file and specifically not about run/debug configurations or tasks.

[image]

Per default this button seems to use the configured python interpreter and runs: `python.exe filename.py`.

However, I want to run files as a module: `python.exe -m filename`

Is that possible somehow?

I found the setting "python.terminal.launchArgs" to add the "-m", but then there is still the problem that just the filename is required without the ".py" extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Code Runner**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extensions and add your own configuration to customize the run command.

After installing the extension, add the following configuration in the ***settings.json*** and the running command is `python -m filename`.

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "code-runner.customCommand": "python -m $fileNameWithoutExt",
```

Then use *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Run Custom Command`* to execute the command. shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

[image]

This is the execution effect:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the python debugger. There it is possible to add specific launch configurations. When creating the `launch.json` file, select python module.
I'm not sure if you can start it without the debugger attached.

[This](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) should include all the details you need.

Comment: I want to change the "run python file" button, but launch configurations don't affect the button's behaviour. I could add a launch configuration for every single file that I want to run as a module, but still I would have to select the correct configuration instead of just clicking the button.

Comment: You might be able to make a generic launch configuration with a variable (e.g. `${file}`, as used in the template "Python: Current File") as module name. Then you just need to use the debug button instead of the run button. But The Code Runner extension as suggested by JialeDu might be a more convenient solution for you.